# Assign instance id when the wpf app has multiple controls on page identified as one instance

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests

Is it possible to use searchProperties.Add("Instance","1"); to assign instance id where the wpf application has  multiple controls like buttons or combo boxes which are recognized as one instance of the control.  If yes then how to do this?  Any code sample is appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar case which found three possible controls. One was visible and two not visible. In my case solved by using `FindMatchingControls` and then looking at the `Left` and `Top` properties. For the invisible control these would be negative.

Comment: Unfortunately the controls for our app are all visible on the screen so this approach would not work

Comment: I found the solution for my controls by calling `FindMatchingControls` then printing lots of field and property values for each found control. Print was via `WriteLine` calls to a suitable output stream. That allowed me to find some fields that distinguished the wanted control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An addendum to AdrianHHH's excellent suggestion is to iterate through the FindMatchingControls collection and figure out which one is the one you want. If it's always collection[3] then you can identify it and act on it as such.

Your code would look like this:

```
       var button = new WinButton(winWindowChild(mainParentCtName, childParentCtName));
          //if you pass parents when you construct an object it can speed up find

        button.SearchProperties.Add(/*any identifying properties*/);
        var allButtons = button.FindMatchingControls();

        //test code
        foreach (var btn in allButtons)
            Mouse.Click(btn); //watch this to figure out what order the buttons are iterating through, then remove loop

        Mouse.Click(allButtons[3]);
        Mouse.DoubleClick(allButtons[0]);
        Mouse.Hover(allButtons[1]);
```

Comment: I am trying out this solution but I get an error passing the Parent reference (winWindowChild(mainParentCtName, childParentCtName))

Comment: I was able to get past the parent reference issue.  I copied coded from the designer file and used it to reference the Parent.

Comment: It now appears that coded ui is looking for the parent to be unique.  The child is not reached as the Parent is not unique.  Can I somehow tell the tool to ignore parent?  I was also looking at finding a way to click on the x, y coordinates.  Not able to figure out how to find the location respective of the screen and not the control.

Comment: (winWindowChild(mainParentCtName, childParentCtName)) was placeholder code for the actual parent which should be unique.

We've had luck using new WinButton(Root.Parent.Parent.ImmediateParent) notation (please note that these names are also placeholder names) getting the names for all the parents from the designer where they are mapped.

Comment: My issue is that the parent is not unique.  I used the uimap tool box to tailor (attach child to a unique parent higher up in the hierarchy in the uimap) with some success. This did not work across the board.  The development team added automation ids as the child were not unique therefore I could not add instance id.  Thanks for your help